# Error with messages larger that 16 Kb with WCF REST Service

Tags: wcf, rest

I have WCF REST service that fails on returning the messages larger then 16 Kb:

*The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.*

The excerpt from my configuration is following

```
    <bindings>
   <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpSecureBinding" 
        maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600"
        maxBufferSize="104857600"
        maxBufferPoolSize="104857600">
    <readerQuotas 
        maxDepth="32" 
        maxStringContentLength="8192" 
        maxArrayLength="104857600"
                maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
        maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />

     <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
     </security>

    </binding>
   </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
 <services>
   <service name="TlvOepRelay.RelayService">

      <endpoint address="" 
        binding="webHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="webHttpSecureBinding" 
        name="HttpGetEndpoint"
        contract="TlvOepRelay.IRelayService" />

   </service>
  </services>
```

Nothing mentioned on from various discussions unforfunatelly does not help: after applying the suggested changes in config file the error message remains. 
Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like the error is on the client (receiving) side - can you post your client config?

Comment: It's a WCF REST service and actually the client is a browser. It simply invokes the service by endpoint's URL.